# Stuck when shutdown kubuntu or linuxmint KDE

Tags: shutdown, kubuntu-netbook

I am using kubuntu 16.04 and I have a big problem when shutting down computer. When I open a heavy task such as android studio or matlab and then close it, I have to wait for abour ten minutes or more before shutting down the computer. If not, the computer will be stuck when click shutdown and I have to turn it off by holding power button. I had the same problem when I used linux mint KDE. Anyone can help me ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo systemctl poweroff`.  It helps to actually safely kill all the processes and shut the machine down.